# How to get DEFAULT ERROR message along with Custom RAISERROR message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 data-centre Edition, I have this stored procedure in which I am raising a custom error message using raiserror. Is there a way to also get the defualt error message of sql server. The code for the store procedure is as follows.

```
CREATE Procedure usp_SomeName
@StableName         nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@StableID           INT = NULL OUTPUT,
@StableDescription ntext = NULL,
@Picture            image = NULL,
@ReturnCode         int = NULL OUTPUT,
@ReturnMessage      nvarchar(100) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY

           IF @StableName IS NULL
             RAISERROR('Validation Failed: Stable name cannot be null', 16,1)

           IF EXISTS (SELECT StableName from dem.TableName
                        WHERE StableName = @StableName)
              RAISERROR('Validation Failed: Stable Name already Exists',16,1)

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
          INSERT INTO TableName(StableName, [Description], Picture)
          VALUES (@StableName, @StableDescription, @Picture)

          COMMIT TRANSACTION
        SELECT @ReturnCode = 0 , @ReturnMessage = 'Sucess! New Stable Details has added.'
        SELECT @StableID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH 
       IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
         ROLLBACK TRAN

       SELECT @ReturnCode = ERROR_NUMBER(), @ReturnMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

          SELECT @ReturnCode AS ReturnCode, @ReturnMessage AS ReturnMessage,
                 ERROR_LINE()   AS ErrorLine,
                 ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
                 ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    END CATCH

   SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END

GO
```

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 you'll be able to use THROW(). Until then I think you're out of luck...

Comment: Thank you for reply Aaron. One more questions since you have mentioned sql2012 my company is in talks about whether to upgrade to SQL 2012 or not, as "My Boss" has heard too many stories of too many issues with sql 2012, do you reckon he is right or he is just trying to save some pennies ? :)

Comment: There is always fear and paranoia about new versions. SQL Server 2012 introduced more restrictive licensing which may drive the cost up for some customers but as long as you install SP1 and CU6 there really shouldn't be any technical issues.

Comment: A lot of people misunderstand the cost issue. They change from per-processor to per-core, but they cut the cost by 4 (and more of a discount if you are unlucky enough to use AMD). So really it only becomes more expensive for folks with bleeding edge servers with 6+ core processors. For those with quad-cores the price is about the same as it was before. Software Assurance is a good thing to look into as well, the next time your boss is convinced to buy licenses.

Comment: Did he expect Data Center Edition to be cheaper than any other editions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch and when you raise an error the batch goes to catch and then use @@error_message to see the error message.